What does this mean when I submitted the revised manuscript (the decison is minor revision )?
I have submitted a manuscript to IEEE TRANS Journal.
After rounds of revisions, I have gone through the major revision, minor revision, and minor revision.
I have just submitted the revised manuscript for the latest minor revision accordingly, and after one day, the status is "awaiting reviewer selection".
What does this mean?
Does it indicate that my manuscript will go through another complete review by the newly invited reviewers?
Or, is it just a status means that the ADM is handling the manuscript?

See: https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/55665/75368
